# Python psycopg2 copy_from() to load data throws error for null integer values: DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to load data from a StringIO object of python into a Postgres database table using psycopg2's copy_from() method.

My copy_from fails on the first record itself specifically for a particular (nullable) integer column which has null value ('' without quotes). I have also tried using Python's None keyword instead of '' for NULL values.
It throws me the following error:
**DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY , line 1, column : ""**

The code looks something like this:

```
table_data = StringIO.StringIO()
# Populate the table_data variable with rows delimited by \n and columns delimited by \t
cursor = db_connection.cursor()
cursor.copy_from(table_data, <table_name>)
```

This column  is a smallint column.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, `COPY FROM` (and `copy_from`) encode a NULL value as `\N`.  If you want to use the empty string to mean NULL, you need to [say so explicitly](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from):

```
cursor.copy_from(table_data, table_name, null="")
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue has now been resolved.
However, I get a new error:
DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x92

Should I raise a new question for this?

Comment: that's probably already been answered a zillion times over  :)  it's an encoding problem.  most likely your data is encoded as windows-1252, and you need to decode it.

Comment: I did search the answer for this on stackoverflow and I found questions/answers on similar lines but those didn't solve my problem. I have put up a new descriptive question for that here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619801/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x92-in-position-47-ordinal 
Please have a look. Thanks for your help

Comment: copy_from() method does not allow quoted strings like double quotes.Example row ["python", 598.00]; It sends to db like ""python""