# How do you create an in-memory TSV file with null values, using cStringIO?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, cstringio

I know that I can make a simple in-memory CSV file like this:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
tsv_string = '1\t2\t3\n'
f = StringIO(tsv_string)
```

But how do I adapt this to include `null` / `None` values? I am asking because I am generating my `tsv_string` dynamically using real data. Some of the integer fields are null and I cannot replace them with an empty string since Postgres cannot interpret that correctly.

To give even more background, I am doing this so that I can use `psycopg2`'s `copy_from` function which currently gives me this error due to the reason above:

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

**So the question is, how do I place null values in my in-memory TSV file.** Is there a more suitable file extension to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer from this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617895/python-psycopg2-copy-from-to-load-data-throws-error-for-null-integer-values-d?rq=1)

I had to specify the `null` argument as an empty string:

`cursor.copy_from(f, 'my_table', columns=columns, null='')`